# Blender Wavefront Object: number of vertex in face declaration is bigger than the number of all vertices

Tags: c++, blender, file-format, wavefront

I am trying to load a Wavefront Object into my C++ OpenGL program using my own parser. The parser works for some .obj-files, but at some files it throws an `index out of range exception`. After some debugging I recognized that one line in the file references a vertex with the number `10565`:

```
f 2571/5164/4481 8298/5166/4481 10565/5167/4481
                                ^^^^^
```

But the file only contains `10531` vertices.

**Questions:**

- How is Blender still able to import the file?
- To which vertex refers Blender with '10565' even if it doesn't exist?

Comment: edited: added a link to the project files

Comment: It might be modulus. As in, the vertex you want is 10565 % 10531

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution:

**I had to remove the duplicate vertices.**

Answer (score 1):

The best answer will be in the source -

```
svn co "https://svn.blender.org/svnroot/bf-extensions/trunk/py/scripts/addons/io_scene_obj/"
```

My guess would be to ignore erroneous faces, the other option would be to locate the nearby vertex most likely to be connected to the other two vertices.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But if I ignore the erroneous faces I get this result: [cow ugly.JPG](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/96176682/cow%20ugly.JPG)
Even if it has some similarities with the [original.JPG](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/96176682/cow%20original.JPG),
it is still not  
reasonable.

Comment: Ignoring a face will leave a hole in the mesh where a face should be. Your cow_ugly example appears to be faces constructed from incorrect vertices. Start with some simple shapes and work your way up to 10K vertices.